# Linear operator $(Tf)(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y} f(y)dy,\ \| T\|\leq \pi$

Tags: functional-analysis

a) Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y}( \frac{y}{x})^{1/2}dx=\pi.$

b) Let $T:L^2(0,\infty)\to L^2(0,\infty)$ linear operator such that
$(Tf)(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y} f(y)dy$

Use that $\langle Tf,g\rangle =\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y} f(y)\overline{g(x)}(\frac{y}{x})^{1/4}(\frac{x}{y})^{1/4}dxdy$

show that $\|T\|\leq \pi.$

For (a) with the variable change $u = \sqrt{x}$ is calculated.

For (b), I know, $\|T\|=\sup\left\{|\langle Tf,g\rangle |: \|f\|\leq 1, \|g\|\leq 1\right\}$
But I do not know how to properly $\langle Tf,g\rangle .$
How proves it?

I have this:

$<Tf,g>=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}} (\frac{y}{x})^{1/4}|f(y)|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}} \overline{g}(x)(\frac{x}{y})^{1/4}dxdy
\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\left[ \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+y}(\frac{y}{x})^{1/2}dx\right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y} |f(y)|^2\overline{g}(x)^2(\frac{x}{y})^{1/2}dx\right)^{1/2}\right]dy
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \pi^{1/2}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y} |f(y)|^2\overline{g}(x)^2(\frac{x}{y})^{1/2}dx\right)^{1/2}$

And i have not idea to the finish...  I know should use Fubini...

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in part (a) of your question

Comment: Yes. Now is correct.

Comment: Apply Cauchy--Schwartz to the two dimensional integral with measure $1/(x+y)dxdy$